# spam clicks and impressions google search console

Tags: spam-prevention, spam-bots

I have this issue i can't find any solution
spam clicks and impressions, and doesn't appear in google analytics

**edit:** The main issue is my website is at the medical niche while spam clicks are coming from porn queries, now the website is struggling to appear in my target keywords

[image: spam queries example]

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is.  Please use smaller sentences and lay it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.